# Azure Function VNet integration breaks randomly

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-virtual-network

I'm using Azure Functions with .NET 6 on an S1-tier App Service Plan with regional VNET integration. In our scenario, we execute some SQL queries accessing an On-Prem database which works pretty fine at the first glance. Unfortunately, sometimes the virtual network connection seems to break and our queries run into following error:

```
 A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.) An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.
```

After disconnecting and reconnecting the function from VNET, it starts working again as expected (I found this approach [here](https://www.thebestcsharpprogrammerintheworld.com/2020/07/29/vnet-connection-between-azure-function-or-app-service-stops-working-service-association-links/))

But it seems like this is just a really poor workaround. Does anybody know how to fix this indefinitely? I've already tried creating a new function app but that didn't change anything.

Comment: Hey @! had it solved your problem else you can share more details so I can troubleshoot?

Comment: Hey! All of the settings were right already as else it won't have worked in the periods before the disruption occurred. What did the trick for me, was adding an availability test that executes a simple "SELECT 1" statement via HTTP Trigger. I don't know why, but since then it just works without any interruptions.

Comment: Thank you. Great to know that your issue got resolved. It might be because the connection state got transitioned into idle state when you tried to run queries after initial transaction.

Answer (score 1):

•   According to the error that you are encountering, there might be some **issues with the Firewall** in the on-premises environment or the **TCP/IP connection** being established. Thus, I would suggest you to please check all the issues mentioned in the documentation link below and verify whether all the instances of practices mentioned in it are followed correctly: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/connect/network-related-or-instance-specific-error-occurred-while-establishing-connection

•   Secondly, I would suggest you to please check the **SQL Browser Service** in the on-premises SQL Database server and check whether `‘UDP port 1434’` is whitelisted for communication between the two environments or not along with **TCP 1434**. Also, when executing SQL queries to access the on-premises SQL DB, ensure that the `instance name` is input correctly along with the **port number**. Also, when mentioning the port number, ensure that it is `preceded by ‘,’ and not ‘:’`.

•   Finally, I would suggest you **enable diagnostic logging** for an app service plan by referring to the below documentation link that will help you figure out the reason for your connection error to the SQL DB. Also, you can **browse through the Kudu console** by accessing the url:- `https://****.scm.azurewebsites.net/ (enter your website name instead of ****)`. You should be able to find the log files under the debug console. Please check if there are any failure logs: -

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs#:~:text=To%20enable%20application%20logging%20for,itself%20off%20in%2012%20hours](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs#:%7E:text=To%20enable%20application%20logging%20for,itself%20off%20in%2012%20hours).

https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Investigating-issues

Note: - Please check whether your `API URL connection string` used in the function app is being replaced correctly and troubleshoot your **connection variables** thoroughly.